# trying to build Tetris game in flutter through drag drop functionality of images to gridview.builder ,stuck at finding the index where to place img

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, tetris, flutter-gridview

I am trying to build Tetris game in flutter through drag drop functionality of images to gridview.builder but I have no idea how to put image block to gridview accordingly

Like I have 's' type of block image, i dragged over gridview but don't know how to fit s on gridview blocks

If anyone have any idea please help.

I tried drag drop functionality between image and gridview
I am expecting to share the possibility of how to put image of 's' block over gridview view block

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.